# Using get_current_screen for admin logic

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to change a text under the url wp-admin/admin.php?page=erp-accounting-expense and I have created the following function but didn't seem to work on getting the admin page correctly. Kindly advise. Thanks!

```html
add_action('current_screen', 'current_screen_callback');
function current_screen_callback($screen) {
    if( is_object($screen) && $screen->id == 'erp-accounting-expense' ) {
        add_filter( 'gettext', 'erp_filter_gettext', 99, 3 );
    }
}

function erp_filter_gettext( $translated, $original, $domain ) {

    // Use the text string exactly as it is in the translation file
    if ( $translated == "Receive Payment" )  {
        $translated = "Make Payment";
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
add_action('current_screen', 'current_screen_callback');
function current_screen_callback($screen) {
    if( is_object($screen) && $screen->id == 'accounting_page_erp-accounting-expense' ) {
        add_filter( 'gettext', 'erp_filter_gettext', 99, 3 );
    }
}

function erp_filter_gettext( $translated, $original, $domain ) {

    // Use the text string exactly as it is in the translation file
    if ( $translated == "Receive Payment" )  {
        $translated = "Make Payment";
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

Solved